# Converting Json data to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
      $.getJSON("/json/cats.json", function(json) {

        var html = "";
        // Only change code below this line.
        json.forEach(function(val){
                     var keys = Object.keys(val);
                     html+="<div class='cat'>";
                     keys.forEach(function(key){
                       html+="<strong>"+key+"</strong>;"+val[key]+"<br>";
                     });
        html+="</div><br>";
                     });


        // Only change code above this line.

        $(".message").html(html);

      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <h2>Cat Photo Finder</h2>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 well message">
      The message will go here
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Get Message
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I am an amateur front end developer I just finished some basic JS and started learning about json and jquery but this above bit of code is going over my head.
Could some one please explain the javascript part of it.

Comment: What is your question? Can you edit you post with an actual question? What is the problem, does your code give errors, what is the expected result?

Comment: paste your `cats.json` data also

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I got this as a task on free code camp, you can look it up at freecodecamp.com
 The task is titled convert json data to html

Comment: so what is the problem if you not understand that things than start leaning and see tutorial for this not ask question like that type

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // means that whenever the document is ready you get an annonimous function

    $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {// this is jQuery selector for an element in the DOM called getMEssage (this is the ID)
      $.getJSON("/json/cats.json", function(json) { // this gets the JSON data from /json/cats.json

        var html = ""; //you create an empthy variable called html
        // Only change code below this line.
        json.forEach(function(val){ // you go over each element in the json object that came from the cats.json file
                     var keys = Object.keys(val); // you get the key
                     html+="<div class='cat'>";// you add a div element with the class cat to the html variable you did create at every iteration
                     keys.forEach(function(key){ //you itewrate over all keys
                       html+="<strong>"+key+"</strong>;"+val[key]+"<br>"; // you add the key (in bold text) + the value for the key (not in bold) to the html and you break the row
                     });
        html+="</div><br>"; // now you close the div element and you break the row
                     });


        // Only change code above this line.

        $(".message").html(html); // then you select all the elements with the message class and you set their html to be equal to your variable called html

      });
    });
  });
```

Hope it helps.
All the best, 
PIY

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { //function get executed when page finished all loading (i.e. html, JS/CSS files)
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function() { //clicking on an element (can be button) with ID "getMessage" triggers this function
          $.getJSON("/json/cats.json", function(json) { //Jquery method to fetch a file from given address and expected file should be a JSON file

        var html = "";
        // Only change code below this line.
            json.forEach(function(val){ // on successfully getting the file this function would be triggered
                 var keys = Object.keys(val); //storing keys to a variable "keys"
                 html+="<div class='cat'>"; //appending HTML object to a var
                 keys.forEach(function(key){ // loop through all the keys
                   html+="<strong>"+key+"</strong>;"+val[key]+"<br>"; // add all the keys as strong text and place values next to them
                 });
    html+="</div><br>"; // close the div and append line break
                 });


    // Only change code above this line.
   $(".message").html(html); //append the newly created HTML to a section (can be div) with ID "message" to show up on HTML page.
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For any given array of json `input` you could map over it and return a string representation for each element.

```js
let input = [
  { name: 'Foo', id: 42 },
  { name: 'Bar', id: 1337 },
  { name: 'Biz', id: 12 }
];

let elems = input.map(e => `<li>${e.name} (${e.id})</li>`);
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = elems.join('');
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```